# algorithm (pseudo-code) to compute higher order polynomial

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math

I need an algorithm to compute higher order polynomial from 3 random variables e.g. X,Y,Z

I need the up to degree 9 of polynomials. for example:

```
Degree 2:
X * Y
X * Z
Y * Z
Degree 3:
X * Y * Z
X^2 * Y
X^2 * Z
Y^2 * X
Y^2 * Z
Z^2 * X
Z^2 * Y
.
.
.
Degree 9:
X^3*Y^3*Z^3
.
.
.
```

I believe three inner "for loop" will solve this but I can't figure it out.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: ...What language are you using to implement?

Comment: The language is not important and a pseudo code is enough. For the reference I must implement it in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force Java solution.  You simply can iterate over all exponent values from through 9 inclusive and retain those configurations where the overall order be less than or equal to 9.

```
for (int i=0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j <= 9; ++j) {
        for (int k=0; k <= 9; ++k) {
            if (i + j + k >= 2 && i + j + k <= 9) {
                System.out.println("x^" + i + "*y^" + j + "*z^" + k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can port this over to R fairly easily, but as loops tend to be frowned upon in R, there is probably a more proper (and possibly faster) way to do it.

Comment: You will be missing the order two polynomials.
The first order you compute is x * y * z.
You need to x^0, y^0 and z^0.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! This actually does the job. The advantage of the brute force is that you don't have to think too much about it. However this is not the most efficient way to implement it. So far the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

In Python for example I would do something like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

for p in permutations([0,1,2,3] * 3,  3):

    if sum(p) >= 2:

        print("x^{} * y^{} * z^{}".format(*p))
```

Basically, loop through all length 3 permutations of coefficients `[0,1,2,3] * 3` (0 to 3 repeated 3 times).

Here is a link to Heap's algorithm for generating the permutations along with some pseudo code:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: This may work in python but is not a general approach to this problem. `itertools` and `permutations` are not available in all programming languages. The question tends not to be language specific. Thanks anyway.

Comment: At least anyone can look up how to code up a permutation algorithm in any language. Plus this approach extends easily to say 10 or 20 variables (without 10 or 20 for loops).